# Vimgrep: How to create an arglist using find command?

Tags: vim, find, vimgrep

I want to use  **vimgrep** to refactor some code in a python project. Let say that this is the project structure:

```
./
  nlp/
  test/
  setup.py
  README.md
```

Both the nlp and test folder contains some python files. Assuming that my pwd is the `./` directory. I would like to include all the files from this command:

```sh
find . -type f -name "*.py"
```

To be included in my args list in vim, like this:

```
:args `find . -type f -name "*.py"
```

And then search the pattern using the vimgrep using:

```
:vimgrep /pattern/g ##
```

The problem is I cannot create the args list, it is giving me some metacharacter error in the vim.

NOTE: Though I can do this:

```
:args `find . -type f`
```

EDIT: The exact error is:

**E79: Impossible de développer les métacaractères**
"`find . -type f -name" [Nouveau fichier]

Which means unable to develop to metacharacters.

Comment: What's wrong with `args **/*.py` ?

Comment: Thanks I just came to know that from a colleague and it works, but how to make the find command work?

Comment: I guess you need `:h fnameescape()`

Comment: Gonna check that !

Comment: Can you give the exact error please?